# Read Text File and Code Data Into Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble using Scanner to read a text file and place the data into a multi dimensional array.

Here is an example of one line in the text file:

United States    45,785,090 19.8    14.3

I am trying to accomplish what is hardcoded below without actually hardcoding the data:

```
Object data[][] = { { "United States", 45785090, 19.8, 14.3 },
    { "Russia", 11048064, 4.8, 7.7 },
    { "Germany", 9845244, 4.3, 11.9 },
    { "Saudi Arabia", 9060433, 3.9, 31.4 },
    { "United Arab Emirates", 7826981, 3.4, 83.7 },
    { "United Kingdom", 7824131, 3.4, 12.4 },
    { "France", 7439086, 3.2, 11.6 },
    { "Canada", 7284069, 3.1, 20.7 },
    { "Australia", 6468640, 2.8, 27.7 },
    { "Spain", 6466605, 2.8, 13.8 }};
```

Comment: so where is your code? Show us your code.

Comment: Well, how does the text-file look?

Comment: Looks like you are thinking of inner Arrays containing mixed Strings and ints. Not possible in Java!

Comment: Do you have a POJO for the data model?? does it need to be an array of objects? or can be a custom classs????

Comment: Why are you using a scanner? Using FileReader to read a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String[]> array = new ArrayList();
Scanner scan= new Scanner(new File("./myFile.txt"));
String str;
String auxiliary= new String[4];
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    str= scan.readLine();
    auxiliary=str.split(" "); // you can use also the \\s
    array.add(auxiliary);
}
```

after you can use this to get the correct type:
    Integer.parseInt(array.get(line)[position_in_line]);

I hope it helped.